# Is there a function or a package that could help me identify the word distance between specific words/terms?

Tags: r, text-mining

For my literature search on various databases, I employ proximity search operators in combination with turnication i.e. I f I am interested in a compound word such as "literal comprehension", I write it as "literal✶ N2 comprehen✶". By doing this I allow the databases to return me only the studies that contain the words "literal" and "comprehension" and their derivatives (e.g, comprehend, literally, comprehensive, etc.) always with a maximum of two words between them and written in the given order or the other way around e.g., "comprehend literally" "literally comprehend", "literally comprehensive" etc. etc.
There is no theoretical foundation to tell me how many words I should ask to exist between the words of interest; either N2 or N200, it is up to me.
Assume that I am interested in finding proof for "literal comprehension" in educational studies. To avoid all this manual work, i thought of using some text mining tool in R, to load all the texts of interest and somehow discover how many words , on average, are usually between literal✶ and comprehend✶. in the texts I have loaded. If I would be able to do this somehow, I would be more efficient in my proximity search. Therefore, I would be more confident to use a specific *n* in "literal✶ N*n* comprehen✶".
I hope I made my point clear and any suggestion or direction would be super helpful

Comment: Check out the package `stringdist` for the basic answer. For your task, you are describing a "skip-gram". The concept of lemmatization (or the less sophisticated stemming) may get you in the right direction for variations of words. The package `udpipe` one of a few powerful tools to help you accomplish that. A lot going on here, the question is asking a lot, but hopefully this gives you some things to google.

Comment: Yeah I know my question is too complicated but I appreciate your feedback. I’ll Google these you mention and see where it gets me. Otherwise, I’ll try to write the question again more clearly

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.